# MongoDb - Do i need an index on a second field when using deleteOne

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a simple collection  `events`

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e2a9bb9dcb646448f9409b3"),
    "year" : 2020,
    "employee_id" : "5e1afe5ab7bad92b20365476",
    "event" : ["Holidays"],
    "total" : 21,
    "used" : 1
}
```

and i don't want to be able to delete the documents that have `used` field grater than `0`.

I use this

```js
  db.collection('events').deleteOne({_id: ObjectId("5e2a9bb9dcb646448f9409b3"), used: 0});
```

Do i need to set an index on `used` field if i already use _id?

Thanks

Comment: Not required. There is an index already on the `_id` field. Are you having any performance issue with delete operation? Are there a large number of documents in the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessary. MongoDB already uses `_id` (unique index created by MongoDB) to delete documents.

```
db.collection('events').find({_id: ObjectId("5e2a9bb9dcb646448f9409b3"), used: 0}).explain();

"winningPlan" : {
    "stage" : "FETCH",
    "filter" : {
        "used" : {
            "$eq" : 0.0
        }
    },
    "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "indexName" : "_id_",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "multiKeyPaths" : {
            "_id" : []
        },
        "isUnique" : true,
        "isSparse" : false,
        "isPartial" : false,
        "indexVersion" : 2,
        "direction" : "forward",
        "indexBounds" : {
            "_id" : [ 
                "[ObjectId('5e2a9bb9dcb646448f9409b3'), ObjectId('5e2a9bb9dcb646448f9409b3')]"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```